# Page not found (404) Password reset link (local test)

Tags: python, django

I have set up the build in password reset in django. It's working until I am going to paste the reset link that I got in the email. When I paste it i get this 404 error:
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/registration/reset/Nw/4o1-b6d03123dbdd2fb0eab5/
Raised by:  taskoftheday.views.taskoftheday

I have the password reset code in an app called registration. But I get the error raised by an app I also have called taskoftheday.

What is wrong?

Django version 1.9

urls.py in registration app

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_user, name='login_user'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_user, name='logout_user'),
    url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

urls.py in main

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^taskoftheday/', include('taskoftheday.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('taskoftheday.urls')),
    url(r'^analytics/', include('analytics.urls')),
    url(r'^progress/', include('progress.urls')),
    url(r'^goals/', include('goals.urls')),
    url(r'^registration/', include('registration.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('registration.urls')),
    url(r'thanks/', views.thanks),
    url(r'thanks_again/', views.thanks_again),
    url(r'^$', views.landing_page),

]
```

Comment: can you post the contents of `urls.py`?

also, which version of Django are you using?

Comment: Thanks I updated the post.
I use django 1.9

Comment: Do you have django.contrib.auth in your INSTALLED_APPS?

Do you have the required templates? password_reset_confirm.html i think it should be inside a folder called registration/

Comment: also, this url `url(r'^', include('taskoftheday.urls')),` might be matching before `url(r'^', include('registration.urls')),` so you're getting routed to the `taskoftheday.urls`

Comment: Thanks! This worked! I moved the `url(r'^', include('registration.urls')),` on top of the taskoftheday url